# Where are the Description and Discussion fields in TFS stored in the SQL database

Tags: sql, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019, warehouse

I've been looking in the TFS_Default Collection and TFS_Warehouse database's but haven't had any luck.

[image: TFS Task Image]

Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information? You **should not** write queries against TFS operational store databases (i.e. `tfs_defaultcollection`).

Comment: Short answer: Just query it, the user I've got set up has Read only.

Long Answer: Create C# Web app that will be able to search for strings depending on what team the user is a part of.

Comment: Then the actual solution to your problem is to use the REST APIs to run a WIQL query. The database schema is undocumented and subject to change, and querying it directly isn't an option at all in Azure DevOps. If you want to make your solution maintainable and portable, then use the REST APIs.

Comment: Thank you I'll be sure to look into those :)

Comment: @DanielGibson Have your checked the answer from @Shamrai? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

TFS_Warehouse does not contain multi-line text fields. For TFS_DefaultCollection, it is not recommended to use operational databases because that may affect TFS performance. Consider to use Rest API:

1. [Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
2. [Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

You can use nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/), [Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops)